# How do you save the value of a global to a text file with Intersystems Caché?

Tags: intersystems-cache

In the terminal, I am printing the value of a global with `zw ^MYGLOBAL`.
How do I save this output to a text file?

Answer (score 3):

Quick nasty way:

```
s f="c:\file.txt" o f:"wns" u f zw ^MYGLOBAL c f
```

The same thing, more verbosely:

```
set f="c:\file.txt"
open f:"wns"
use f
zwrite ^MYGLOBAL
close f
```

Comment: Am I supposed to write this in the cache terminal? I get <SYNTAX> error

Answer (score 2):

As you already mentioned yourself the easiest way to output global/local recursively is using `ZWRITE` command. Output of which could be redirected if you `OPEN` file and then `USE` it, redirecting all write to principal device to this filename.

But as Sergey @SSH mentioned [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33556484/4184121), the better approach is to use `%GO` utility (which essentially does the job similar to `ZWRITE` but output of which could be read later using `%GI` utility. If you want more effeciency in handling binary data then recomended approach is to output global(s) using `%GOF` and read them back using `%GIF`

Answer (score 1):

To turn on logging, in the terminal click File → Logging, or Alt + L.
This saves all the output of the terminal to a log file, until you turn off logging.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to use the `^%GO` utility. This way, you will be able to import your globals back with `^%GI`.

```
do ^%GO
```

Comment: Is there any way to run this as a single line and skip the interactive input?

Comment: No, not an easy way. For programmatic output it's better to use $system.OBJ.Export.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly a ZW format, but try

```
do $system.OBJ.Export("Global.GLB","backup.xml")
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error: "ERROR #6304: Unable to export item 'Global.GLB' because XML export does not support items of this type."

Comment: What version of Caché are you running?